# gapi.auth.authorize 404 File not found using "user_id" parameter

Tags: google-drive-api, google-chrome-app

I am getting a 404 "File not found" when using user_id in the gapi.auth.authorize method. It was working before and kind of out of the blue it now gives a 404 not being able to get the file.

Basically when a user is signed in with multiple accounts it tries to authenticate him with this parameter

gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes,immediate: true,user_id: email}, handleAuthResult);

Any idea what might be happening? In the documentation I don't see the parameter there. Is this discontinued or something?

Best regards,
Joao Garin

Comment: Is this a Chrome App (a.k.a. packaged app)? You have the google-chrome-app tag on your question. It would help if you clarified the context under which this is occurring (Chrome App, extension, hosted app, web page, etc.).

Comment: This happens In a google chrome app usng the drive sdk with the "open with"menu. Basically it goes to the site with the id of the document in question. And when you have multiple accounts the first step is to "choose" the account you want and so using this information to authorize with the correct account (using user_id).

Answer (score 0):

The name of the corresponding URL parameter is [`login_hint`](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#formingtheurl), and according to the [reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthauthorize) any parameters you pass into the method are added to the URL, so try using that instead.